# Is there any way to create a dynamic class based on list of strings of variable names in java?

Tags: java

I have a list of variables names (which I will fetch from Database) as:

```
List<String> variableNames= ["name", "age", "gender"];
```

and these variable names will be dynamic based on table data in database.

Now, I want to be able to create a **dynamic class** out of these variables, like:

```
public class PersonDTO{

private String name;
private String age;
private String gender;

//getter and setters

}
```

Is there anyway, I can do this in java?

Comment: Something like this: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/json.htm#TLADG573

Comment: How would you access it then? Lets say you had a `PersonDTO p = createDynamicClass( listOfStrings );` Then what will you do? p.name?

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have a way of creating dynamic variables.
You need to declare variable in your code itself.
You could instead use a map in some way to achieve your goals.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("name","value");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map<String, Object>` where DB column is key and the column data is the value of map.

```
Map<String, Object> PersonDTO = new Hashmap<>();

map.put("age", new Integer());
map.put("name", new String());

String name = (String)map.get("name");
```